# What is the maximum image resolution opencv can read (using cv2.imread()) in PYTHON

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a OpenCV project and we load images from different sources. It was working fine when loading typical image resolution, like 680x420, 1920x1080, 2560x1440.
When we try a very high-resolution image at 4K, OpenCV tends to become slower. The thing is if we run image processing, it is very slow (we need to stream back as MJPEG), worst part we get a segfault.

Back to the question, is there a limit resolution for the OpenCV to process? I don't see any information related to this.

PS. note we are running the project on a decent pc, so memory is not an issue.

Comment: Not sure why it is flagged as duplicate, the linked question is working on c++, doesn't seem to apply to python.

Comment: OpenCV **is in C++**, the python one is only a wrapper.